# ManyToMany field not getting saved Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an app named `billing`. Following are models in my app.

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50,decimal_places=4)

class Product(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType,related_name="products")
    mac_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    product_unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class BillRecord(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="billrecords",blank=True)
    send_sms = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    send_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    invoice = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='invoices/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BillRecord, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        total_products = Product.objects.filter(assigned=False)
        self.products.add(*total_products)
```

After saving the `BillRecord` object and querying the object's `products` returns me `billing.Product.None`

How can I add `products` in my save method of `BillRecord` model.

Comment: Can you tell how you are saving this ?  Because the above code is just working...

Comment: I'm adding BillRecord object from django admin side

Comment: I answered... Please check...

Comment: Did you checked out my answer ? Is it solved your problem ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Nop It didn't

Comment: Okay one sec let med update my answer with save_model...

Comment: Updated try that one

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your save method,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    item = super(BillRecord, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    total_products = Products.objects.filter(assigned=False)
    item.products.add(*total_products)
    item.save()
```

First, call the super().save method,  then add the objects you want to associate to the self object.

Comment: Zahid when I followed your method I'm getting error like `"<BillRecord: test>" needs to have a value for field "billrecord" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Answer (score 0):

Many to  many save in Admin will not work in normal way. You need to override the Admin class like this....

```
class BillRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(ArticleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        total_products = Product.objects.filter(assigned=False)
        form.instance.products.add(*total_products)


admin.site.register(BillRecord, BillRecordAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add many-to-many field objects to the billrecord object, thats why your are getting error, "

```
"<BillRecord: test>" needs to have a value for field "billrecord" before this many-to-many relationship can be used"
```

First, You need to save BillRecord model's object, and then add that queryset of objects to many-to-many relation.